# Por que a numeração dos meses do objeto Date começa no zero?

Tags: javascript, data, actionscript-3, característica-linguagem

Por exemplo:

```
var data:Date = new Date();
trace(data.month); //Supondo que o mês seja Janeiro: 0
```

Eu gostaria de alguns detalhes, pois sei que não é apenas em ActionScript e Javascript que acontece isso. Por que não simplificar o contador do mês para que em uma conversão seja fácil de compreender, obtendo os números retornados exatamente como os meses do ano (Janeiro = 1, Fevereiro = 2, Março = 3)?

Pois sempre temos que diminuir 1:

```
var dataStr:String = "28/04/2014";
var data:Date = new Date(dataStr.substr(6,4), (dataStr.substr(3,2)-1), dataStr.substr(0,2), 0, 0, 0);
trace(data.month); //3
```

Por que isso acontece?

Comment: Porque `data.month` é um array e todo array começa do zero, acredito que seja isso.

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha Então e se for o dia do mês começa em 1 por não ser um array? Tudo que seja um array para que se possa atribuir um valor a cada elemento ex: 0=>"Janeiro" ou 0=>"Segunda-Feira" começa em 0?

Comment: @JorgeB. [comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14166/porque-os-meses-do-objeto-date-comeca-no-zero?noredirect=1#comment24929_14173)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso acontece porque toda lista/enum/contadores/arrays, por convenção começam em `0`

Assim sendo...
entenda que continuam sendo 12 meses, só q eles irão de 0 a 11, Janeiro a Dezembro.

Se você quiser que eles representam exatamente o mês q quer, só adicionar `+1`.

Se você criar uma lista em `javascript`.

```
var arrayLista = [];
arrayLista.push("First");
```

Se tiver um debugger ou algo do tipo, poderá ver que a estrutura desse Array, inicia da seguinte maneira:

```
arrayLista = { [0] => "First" }
```

Se incrementar novamente com o `push`, verá algo assim:

```
arrayLista = { [0] => "First", [1] = "Second" }
```

Comment: Então porque é que o número de dias é de 1 a 31 e não de 0 a 30?

Comment: Entendo, creio que funciona da mesma maneira em relação ao dia da semana (Domingo, Segunda...). Mas e porque os dias não são da mesma maneira? E o ano?

Comment: @biio Provavelmente porque os dias e anos não precisam ser mapeados para nomes, enquanto os meses e os dias da semana precisam. Seja como for, é uma decisão arbitrária da linguagem.

Comment: A razão é que o estes parâmetros como Dias da semana e os Meses são derivados de um objeto Array, correto? Então é o que simplifica a conversão de 'string' (Janeiro) para um int (0). Será por isso que se utiliza-se como um Array?

Comment: Nesse caso vc diz em `meses[0]` e sair `Janeiro`?? Se sim, é por isso mesmo, onde `0` é a posição do array que armazena a string `Janeiro`

Answer (score 3):

O motivo pelo qual os meses do ano começam do zero é uma grande falha no projeto da API de datas do Java e que, em minha opinião, ocorre em outras linguagens também, como Javascript.

Isso provavelmente é resultado do uso de um vetor interno ou então ao uso interno na JVM de APIs do C++, como citado [nesta questão do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar), que levou a Sun a escolher o zero como índice base dos meses.

Digo que foi uma falha de projeto porque não é a toa que toda semana, seja no trabalho, seja em fóruns, me deparo com um problema causado por um equívoco do desenvolvedor. Eu mesmo, já sabendo disso, acabei caindo no mesmo engodo algumas vezes.

É totalmente contra-intuitivo. Por exemplo, você recebe em um input o texto `2014-04-28` e faz um *parse* para data usando o padrão `yyyy-MM-dd`. Então você manda imprimir o mês e vê o valor `3`. Na minha primeira experiência com isso eu tive certeza que era um bug no meu programa. O mesmo ocorreu com vários colegas.

Porém, a diferença é que em outras linguagens como Javascript a formatação de *parse* de datas não é tão frequente ou necessário como em linguagens de *back end*.

Comment: Sim, mas isso ocorre em outras linguagens também. Em todas elas houve esta mesma falha de projeto?

Comment: @biio Sim, eu sei. Linguagens que receberam a mesma influência. Se é uma falha, depende da API em geral. A questão é: você vê sistemas com bugs ou exibindo datas incorretas nessas linguagens tão frequentemente quanto em Java?